# Program with Internet Explorer 7 dependency on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-xp, internet-explorer

I need to execute a *very* old program (that parses HTML files) that seems dependent on Internet Explorer 7 components being installed: if I run the program on a Windows XP machine that has IE7, it works, while if I run it on XP with IE8 the parse result is corrupted. So having IE7 is the key.

My problem is that I need to avoid old Windows versions for security reasons. What actions can I try to make the program run correctly on Windows 10?

---

I've tried using Windows' compatibility mode for the old program, but that didn't work. Setting compatibility mode in IE11 to 7 didn't work either. Can I downgrade to IE7 on Windows 10? Can I sandbox the program with IE7? Can I copy old IE7 system files to Windows 10 somehow?

This question is similar to [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/1019776/how-to-run-internet-explorer-7-on-windows-10), but I don't want to use IE myself for browsing, merely use it as a dependency for another program.

Comment: I know you mention security issues, but why not use a VM?

Comment: You may need to build an XP Virtual Machine (VMware Workstation or similar to do this). Then find a copy of IE 7 to run on the virtual machine. None of this above will work natively in Windows 10

Comment: For security reasons, it is not acceptable to run Windows XP as a virtual machine in my environment.

Comment: It is impossible to run or install IE7 on Windows 10.  What you want is not possible

Comment: If a WinXP VM is unacceptable for security reasons, then the program that has the dependency should also be unacceptable for security reasons, and needs to be replaced.

Comment: You won't be able to install the components, because they will have the same file names as current WIndows/IE components, and will thus conflict, since the program that ostensibly needs them will be trying to call them from the standard location.

Comment: What, precisely, does this old program _do_ that can't be replaced?

Comment: Since Windows 7, possibly even before, IE has been _tightly_ bound to Windows itself, and if you replace the files such that you 'break' the standard IE, you will probably _also_ break the File Explorer and the UI itself.

Comment: If you try copying old IE7 files to Windows 10, you stand a good chance of breaking the machine. If you cannot run virtual machines in your work environment, then you need to get a different application to solve your problem.

Comment: The constraints you have been progressively putting on the problem admit to exactly _one_ solution: You will have to set up a "air-gapped" Win XP box and run the program in question on it, using "sneaker-net" to transfer pre- and post-processed data between it and your "regular" environment.

Comment: Correction: The second solution is to recode it, as should have been done _years_ ago when IE7 went out of support.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run Internet Explorer 7 on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1019776/how-to-run-internet-explorer-7-on-windows-10)

Comment: @Moab: No, I'm only interested in using IE7 components as dependencies for another program, not using IE7 itself.